# Convert ODT to doc/rtf format in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi, odt

I have an application which kicks out a various documents in various formats.  This is it's main purpose.  I am using japser for most of the non excel documents and now I realise I may have made a mistake!  (I can't afford Aspose !).  I am operating in a Windows environment.

Essentially many of the documents are produced in both odt and doc format.  The requirement for the Word version is for doc so as to be compatible for the maximum number of users (who are outside my organisation).

For this I am exporting in rtf format to a doc suffixed file.  So far so good except the tables are exported as text input boxes not tables and the users are very upset that they can't tab between cells (we missed this in testing).  This seems like something that cannot be sorted out simply in report configuration.  the rtf export simply does not export tables as tables.

I considered saving as docx and using poi to convert to doc but this doesn't seem so simple

- lack of an interface between xwpf and hwpf.
- there seems to be a bug in jasper export to docx which sets the margins to 0 and causes printing warnings.  Probably surmountable but as that was a quick & dirty fix idea it is beginning to seem more effort than such a messy solution is worth.

This leaves me with the idea of converting the odt files to doc.  I've had a quick look at jodconverter but it seems so long since anyone has done anything with this that I'm not convinced it is the way to go (I'm also not sure it is compatible with OpenOffice 4.1 which is what I've downloaded although I guess I could back out of that?).

So the main part of this question is - is there a reasonably simple way to  convert odt to doc/rtf in java code (I don't really want the overhead of sending documents to external conversion sites).  I guess an aside would be for any serious Jasper guru's - is there a way of exporting to rtf/doc format with tables as table objects rather than collections of adjacent text input boxes ?

I've tried to lay this out in full, apologies if it's a little verbose.  Any help greatly appreciated (the simpler the solution the better!).

Comment: The **odt-to-docx** conversion can be done on purely XML level (XSLT + jar:file: URI FileSystem). That would require a bit dreadful maintenance (XML and XSLT). But seems more reliable than too large dependance. But then one wonders why the docx generation is so lacking.

Comment: Yes initially the spec was for for docx and I bottled out of XSLT/XSL-FO as I'm fairly new to these technologies and had enough on my plate.  I'm beginning to wish I'd bitten the bullet now though!

Comment: Developing with XSLT is time consuming (small steps, sometimes puzzling), so it is a hard choice to take. On the other hand, it delivers.

Comment: I've had the go ahead to move to docx so I'm leaving this question now (!).  I just wanted to note for future reference that the margin error in Jasper was my fault and is not a Jasper error (any longer).  I had updated my jasper eclipse plug in to the latest version but not the jar in my application itself (doh!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [JODConverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/jodconverter/) which does conversion between ODT and DOC(X) but there's litte documentation about this library and it's no longer maintained.

According to the little doc there is ([here](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/wiki/GettingStarted) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/wiki/Configuration)), here's a little example to convert an odt to a doc file (you need to have OpenOffice or LibreOffice installed locally)

```
OfficeManager officeManager = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration().setOfficeHome(new File("<path to office home>")).buildOfficeManager();
officeManager.start();

OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(officeManager);
converter.convert(new File("test.odt"), new File("test.doc"));

officeManager.stop();
```

`<path to office home>` must be replaced with the path to the home directory of LibreOffice or OpenOffice (the directory that contains the `soffice.bin` file).

Comment: Thanks.  I had considered the jodconverter (as mentioned) but it seems so long since anyone has touched it that I'm a little wary about adding it into a new application.  If no other solution comes along then this may be the only thing I can do though.  As I can't work on this for a week or two I will leave the question open for a while on the off chance and then mark this as a good answer if no one comes up with a miracle fix!  Thanks again.